# Copy sqlite table with mixed column order

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to copy all data from sqlite table to another one (reason being changing primary key and recommended way is to create new table, copy data, rename, etc).
Something along:

```
insert into new_table select * from old_table;
drop old_table;
alter table new_table rename to old_table;
```

Now problem is, that sometimes when I create new table, it's order of columns is not the same and data is completely messed up. Not sure why, probably cause some people have brand new table and some have old table which lived trough lot of upgrade scripts. Anyway my point is, I need to make sure every column is inserted into correct column. I can for sure just name all the columns manually, but I'd like this to work even if I add some columns in future and also for other tables. I can probably somehow query name of columns and then construct query in language that I am using above (kotlin), but I'd like to do this on db level if possible.

It's on android, but not very relevant to the question :)
Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find an explanation/solution to this? I experienced the same issue. I wanted to add check constraints to an existing table, so I had to create anew table, insert data from the old table to the new table, drop the old, and rename the new. It caused all of my columns to have mismatched values.

Comment: Oh I will go to special hell for not posting solution! I ended up using pragma table_info to get columns and then generating query with all columns specified. I will post my kotlin solution as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I had add 1 extra query to get columns.
Other queries had all columns specifically mentioned instead of using star to ensure correct order. My kotlin way:

```
        fun columns(db: SQLiteDatabase, tableName: String): List<String> {
            val sql = "pragma table_info($tableName)"
            return db.rawQuery(sql, arrayOf()).use { cursor ->
                (1..cursor.count).map {
                    cursor.moveToNext()
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"))
                }
            }
        }

        fun copyFromTableToTable(db: SQLiteDatabase, originalTableName: String, backupTableName: String) {
            val columns = columns(db, backupTableName).joinToString(separator = ",")
            db.execSQL("""INSERT INTO $backupTableName
                ($columns)
                SELECT $columns FROM $originalTableName
                """.trimMargin())
            //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE $originalTableName;")
            //db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE $backupTableName RENAME TO $originalTableName;")
        }
```